# AJAX, as answer obtain object

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have 2 php files: index and page. In index.php I write ajax/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        var mas;
        $.ajax({
            url: "page.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "a=aaa&b=bbb",
            success: function (htm) {
                mas = htm;
                alert(htm);         
            }
        });


        $(document).on("click", function () {
            alert(mas['a']);
        });


    });
```

In page.php i have only this code:

```
 echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Data sends successfully, because I obtain in alert message: {"a":"aaa","b":"bbb"}.
When I click on document, alerts : "undefined", please tell, where have I wrong?
I want that alert "aaa"

Comment: I think it may be outside of the variable's scope, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json_encode()` function, does just that...encodes data as JSON. JSON is not a javascript object, it is *notation* for a javascript object. In order to use it as an object, you need to first parse it:

```
mas = JSON.parse(htm);
```

Then you can access values like:

```
alert(mas.a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to the top of the PHP script.

Your JSON data is being treated as an HTML string and not inflated into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell jQuery to parse the JSON from the AJAX call.  To do this add `dataType: 'json'` to `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "a=aaa&b=bbb",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (htm) {
        mas = htm;
        console.log(htm);         
    }
});
```